# Remove an element from List of enum in java

Tags: java, generics, collections, java-8, java-stream

I created a enum and assigned some variables there.

```
public class User{
    // few attributes, constructors , getters, setters

    public enum Role{
        USER,
        DEPARTMENT_HEAD,
        COMPANY_ADMIN,
        SYSTEM_ADMIN,
        MANAGER;
    }
}
```

I need to remove one variable if a contition is true.

```
// getting all attributes inside list
List<Role> roles=new ArrayList<Role>(new User().getRoles());

// try to remove
roles.removeIf(p -> p.equals("SYSTEM_ADMIN"));
```

but when I print, the element hasn't been removed. How can I remove? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since there are a few correct answers already, instead of adding one more, let me add a relevant suggestion: Consider using [EnumSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) instead of an `ArrayList<Role>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're comparing it to `String` and not to enum. This does the job:

```
roles.removeIf(p -> p.equals(Role.SYSTEM_ADMIN));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a static method reference:

```
roles.removeIf(Role.SYSTEM_ADMIN::equals);
```

As pointed out by @Cascader, you could use an EnumSet instead of an ArrayList. It is useless to assign the same role twice to a user. The contract of the `Set` interface prevents this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like bottom

```
roles.removeIf(p -> p.equals(Role.SYSTEM_ADMIN));
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are comparing with String `"SYSTEM_ADMIN"` instead of enum. Changing like below will work,

```
roles.removeIf(p -> p.equals(Role.SYSTEM_ADMIN));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare with String just use `.name()`

```
  roles.removeIf( p -> p.name().equals("SYSTEM_ADMIN"));
```